# JQuery / Live is deprecated, well okay… But is not replaced

Tags: javascript, jquery

***On*** is not working as a replacement for ***live***; as the new ***ON*** is ***NOT*** working for future elements. No problems in my implementations; I'm used to use live and I definitely know when something works or not with jquery.

haml part :

```
.field
        %label Select a file
        = file_field_tag 'post[image]', :class => :dashed
        %span.adder + add another file
```

coffe part :

```
$("span.adder").on "click", (e) ->
    new_field = $(this).closest(".field").clone()
    $(new_field).insertAfter( $(this).closest(".field") )
```

Why the new span.adder added does not have the jquery behaviour attached to their class ?
Something like this shoudl work in that case.

Why the JQuery guys did remove it ?
I don't get it.

---

UPDATE

---

```
$("span.adder").on("click", function(){ });
```

Will not work as live.

It has to be

```
$(document).on("click", "span.adder", function(){ });
```

(thanks for everyone's answers.)

Comment: You're using it wrong. Please show your code that you think can't be made to work with `.on()`.

Comment: I don't know CoffeeScript, but it should be something like `$(document).on "click", "span.adder", (e) ->`

Comment: Meaning you simply replaced `live` with `on`. The implementation is slightly different, have a look at the answers on this question.

Comment: 'kay got it just below.

Comment: I guess I was so much used to apply the behaviour through the element, not through document.

Comment: @SpaceBison Where does it say that `attr()`, `toggle()` and `bind()` is deprecated in 1.9? I know `on()` is *preferred* over `bind()`, but thats about it. `live()` is deprecated since 1.7.

Comment: @David - A rather badly worded comment on my part (which I have removed as it's misleading) - the toggle event toggle() is the only one deprecated (and removed in 1.9) and in the other cases, it's *preferred* as you say to use on() instead of bind and prop() instead of attr().

Comment: Talking about live, bind and on… From what I remind, there was bind, and they added live because, undoubtely, it was the thing everibody would want. Then somehow, they added on. Cool. So now we still have bind, we had live, we have on (well… we have an UPDATED on… that's so cool !); in the end for pretty much doing the same thing. Why is live left, and bind still there ?

Comment: @SpaceBison `prop` is not preferred over `attr`, that is a very common misconception. They don’t even do the same thing - `prop` is for DOM properties, `attr` is for attributes. It’s all in the docs. And while the toggle shorthand *event* is removed, the `toggle()` *function* is still avail in 1.9. Sorry about the rants, I just wanted to clearify this.

Comment: @David Your 'rants' are valid and appreciated. Lesson re-learned: I should refrain from commenting when I know some, but not all of the facts & fine detail :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To work with future elements you must use on document like this

```
$(document).on('click', 'span.adder', function(){
       //Code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Before `.on()` ever came around, `.live()` was already considered an inefficient way to handle event binding, Because of that for future use you have to use `.on()`

e.g:-

```
$(document).on('click', '#yourElement', function() { 
  // your functions here
});
```

There is a better explanation [here](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/on-vs-live-review/)

Comment: How live was considered inneficient ? It always worked on my side

Comment: @Ben It's covered in the explanation link at the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is a replacement. The direct translation would be:

```
$(document).on('click', '.my-selector', function() {});
```

Comment: @roman I've just added it. The new span.adder that are added on the page does not have their jquery behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

They deprecated and remove it because they had better implementation. You see the documentation of `.on()`

```
$(ancestor).on(event, element, function);
```

You should use that as ancestor which is near to that element. There are some performance issues.

Upgrade jQuery version also.

Answer (score 0):

`On` `works as`delegate` used to do, not exactly as .live; you have to use it on a parent and then specify the event and the children that triggers it; something like.

```
$(window).on("click", ".button", function(){ 
    alert("You clicked the button... and I hate alerts");
});
```